# VLC displaying issue via HDMI

Tags: 18.04, graphics, dell, hdmi, vlc

I have switched to 18.04 and I am facing problem when it comes to playing movies on external screen (connected via HDMI). My movies played on VLC look  like on attached screen - screenshot from both screens

[image: screenshot from both screens]

Device: Dell Inspiron 5548

Comment: Have you tried playing any videos on `totem` to see if you get the same issue?

Comment: I have tried on various players (like MPV,SMplayer) and same problem did not appear. The thing is I prefer to use VLC because of its features.